# How to create Javascript concatenation; Several text fields to seperate text areas?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 5 text fields into 2 different formats and have each specific format output to 2 seperate text areas in the same form/page.

The attached code works fine to output to TextArea1 but will not output to my second TextArea2.

So C+A, B+D, E to populate TextArea1.
And C+D, A, B+E to populate TextArea2.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setName()
    {document.forms[0].TextArea1.value = document.forms[0].TextC.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextA.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextB.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextD.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextE.value}
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setName()
    {document.forms[0].TextArea2.value = document.forms[0].TextC.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextD.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextA.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextB.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextE.value}
    </script>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    <table >

<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px">
  <input name="TextA" onkeyup="setName()" type="text" />&nbsp; </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px">
  <input name="TextB" onkeyup="setName()" type="text" /> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px">
  <input name="TextC" onkeyup="setName()" type="text" /> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px">
  <input name="TextD" onkeyup="setName()" type="text" /> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px">
  <input name="TextE" onkeyup="setName()" type="text" /> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px"><strong>C+A, B+D, E</strong><br />
  Created this outcome:<br />
  <input name="TextArea1" onfocus="setName()" style="width: 286px; height: 90px" type="text" wrap="hard" />
  <br />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px"><strong>C+D, A, B+E</strong><br />
  Created this outcome:<br />
  <input name="TextArea2" onfocus="setName()" style="width: 286px; height: 90px" type="text" wrap="hard" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="width: 421px"><strong>Clear Form</strong><br />
  <input name="Reset2" type="reset" value="reset" />&nbsp; </td>
</tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please try to isolate code/markup to the bare essentials necessary to illustrate the problem. Things like CSS etc. won't affect outcome in this case. Also, http://jsfiddle.net and similar are an easy way to provide a live example people can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the function `setName()` defined twice. The first one is being called, but not the second one. Put the code from the second `setName` into the first one, along with the code that's already there, and it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setName()
{
    document.forms[0].TextArea1.value = document.forms[0].TextC.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextA.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextB.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextD.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextE.value;
    document.forms[0].TextArea2.value = document.forms[0].TextC.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextD.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextA.value + ', ' + document.forms[0].TextB.value + ' ' + document.forms[0].TextE.value
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, the second one is being called--later definitions override earlier ones.

Comment: I didn't know that. Learned something new :) but based on the question, the first one is being called. OP said TextArea1 is being populated, which is what the first instance of setName() is doing.

Comment: Could be, but the semantics of JS don't care what any of us think: if you define two methods with the same name, the first is vapor. Also, IMO combining the two methods conflates intrinsically separate behaviors and is a bad habit to get in to.

Answer (score 4):

You have two functions with the same name; the second overwrites the first.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same function name for both of the functions.  The second one is overriding the first.  Change it to `setNameTwo()` or something like that and it should work fine.